# How can I select multiple ids generated by a loop dynamically in Jquery and pass them to AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Ok , I am trying to get different id values through Jquery , and pass them to Jquery AJAX that will hit a PHP file so I can get some data back .... I'm not sure how to get all the multiple different ids because Jquery is only getting the first id of many of the unique id values generated by the while loop .. and I would like each unique ID to also be passed to the AJAX function in Jquery .. Your help would be so much appreciated . I'm still new to the Jquery world

```
<?php
require('../database/connection.php');
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           var ID = $('div#opposition img').attr("id"); alert(ID);
           $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url :'get_users_images.php',
            data:'screen_name='+ ID,
            success: function(result){
             $('div#opposition img').attr('src', result);
           }
         });

         });

    </script>


    <?php
    $select2  = "SELECT * FROM AUTHORS WHERE ID <> $id";   
    $result2 = mysql_query($select2);
    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($result2);
    echo '<div id ="opposition">';
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 

    echo "<img id ='".$row2['Twitter']."' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class ='image".$row2['Twitter']."'/>"; //  echos different ids, 
    }
     ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you getting set of images from ajax return. you could check with Network tag in firefox or chrome debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an *stringified* array of id's like this -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var ID = $('div#opposition img').map(function(){
       return this.id;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_users_images.php',
        data: { screen_name : JSON.stringify(ID)},
        success: function (result) {
            $('div#opposition img').attr('src', result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a way I could pass each one of them to AJAX instead of putting them all into a string ?  because each ID gets processed by the twitter API service which is in PHP .. would that be quicker ?

Comment: @StackOne Then you will end up with multiple http request's equal to the number of Id's, _which seem's inefficient_ , instead you can send all id's and process each id in a function _may be inside loop_ (_don't know much about php though_)

Comment: You know what.. I am thinking that's the way to go with twitter .. Could you please tell me how I could pass each one of these IDS to AJAX instead of putting them into an array ?  I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, Actually , why you are placing the set of images returned by `php` in one 
`img` tag,  `$('div#opposition img').attr('src', result);` .  Rather I think you must do something like  `$('div#opposition').innerHTML(result)` .